# What was the US reaction to the 2004 ruling by the World Court that the Israeli border wall was illegal?

Tags: united-states, international-law, israel, international-court-of-justice

What was the US reaction to [the 2004 ruling by the World Court that the Israeli border wall was illegal](https://news.un.org/en/story/2004/07/108912)?

Did the US accept the ruling or reject it? I'm curious given the fact that the US judge in his dissenting opinion (though I believe it's not called a dissent in this case) wrote that the border wall and settlements were illegal. Given that their own judge gave this opinion, what was the governmental reaction?

Comment: Might be better to refer to "World Court" as "International Court of Justice" so as not to confuse with other entities such as "International Criminal Court"

Answer (score 5):

From [Attacks Against the World Court by Bush, Kerry, and Congress Reveal Growing Bipartisan Hostility to International Law](https://ips-dc.org/attacks_against_the_world_court_by_bush_kerry_and_congress_reveal_growing_bipartisan_hostility_to_international_law/) by Stephen Zunes:

> On July 9, the International Court of Justice (ICJ) determined that
> the Israeli government’s construction of a separation wall running
> through the occupied Palestinian West Bank was illegal. Among other
> things, the ICJ noted that the construction of the first 125 miles
> of the proposed 450-mile barrier “has involved the confiscation and
> destruction of Palestinian land and resources, the disruption of the
> lives of the thousands of protected civilians and the de facto
> annexation of large areas of territory.” The court called on Israel
> to cease construction of the wall, to dismantle what has already
> been built in areas beyond Israel’s internationally recognized
> border, and to compensate Palestinians who have suffered losses as a
> result of the wall’s construction.

> The vote was 14-1, a not-unexpected margin, given the overwhelming
> consensus of international legal experts regarding the
> responsibilities of occupying powers. The majority included the
> highly respected conservative British jurist, Rosalyn Higgins; the
> sole dissenter was the American judge, Thomas Buergenthal.

The US political reaction was overwhelmingly and unanimously
negative. Both the president George Bush and the Democratic
presidential nominee John Kerry denounced the ruling and both disputed
whether the International Court of Justice has jurisdiction:

> Despite the seemingly clear-cut nature of the ruling however, the
> Bush administration, Democratic presidential nominee John Kerry, and
> an overwhelming bipartisan majority of Congress have all gone on
> record denouncing the verdict. Never before has there been such a
> unified negative response by America’s political leadership to a
> decision by the world’s highest court.

> [...] Both Republicans and Democrats have determined that any effort
> to raise legal questions regarding the actions of occupying powers
> must be forcefully challenged.

> The Bush administration quickly challenged the World Court’s
> authority by questioning whether international law should even be
> applied to Israeli-occupied territories. White House spokesman Scott
> McClellan stated, “We do not believe that it is the appropriate
> forum to resolve what is a political issue.” Democratic presidential
> nominee John Kerry concurred, arguing: “It is not a matter for the
> ICJ. … I do not believe that the ICJ should [have] even been
> considering this issue, given that they do not have jurisdiction.”

In fact, Kerry appears to have been even more critical than Bush:

> Both Kerry and Bush stated that they were “deeply disappointed” by
> the World Court’s ruling, but Kerry went on to claim that “Israel’s
> fence is a legitimate response to terror that only exists in
> response to the wave of terror attacks against Israel. The fence is
> an important tool in Israel’s fight against terrorism.” At least
> President Bush was able to say: “I think the wall is a problem. It
> is very difficult to develop confidence between the Palestinians and
> the Israelis with a wall snaking through the West Bank.”

> Further cementing his position, Kerry joined 78 senators—including
> his running mate, Senator John Edwards of North Carolina—in signing
> a strongly worded letter to Kofi Annan criticizing the UN secretary
> general for backing the General Assembly’s decision to ask the ICJ
> to consider the legal questions involved. In the letter, Kerry,
> Edwards, and their Senate colleagues declared that the wall was a
> justifiable and necessary defensive measure by Israel and that
> questioning Israel’s policy cast doubt on the chief UN official’s
> opposition to terrorism.

As the article points out, the matter went to the ICJ precisely
because the threat of an American veto in the Security council
prevented a UN resolution about the matter to pass.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the previous answer, I would like to point out that both the USA and Israel believe that democratic countries that have their own viable court system which is independent from the political system, should preferably not be subject to any International Court.

As a ramification of this principle, not the USA and nor Israel have ever submitted themselves to the International Criminal Court (The ICC).

Although the USA used to be a member state of the International Court of Justice (The ICJ), The USA - ICJ relationship has been quite grim ever since its inception and as a result the US withdrew its submittance in 1985.

See [https://fas.org/sgp/crs/row/LSB10206.pdf?&~nfopt(fileDistorted=8557405207679503&uploadEmbeddedImages=1)](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/row/LSB10206.pdf?&%7Enfopt(fileDistorted=8557405207679503&uploadEmbeddedImages=1))

If you want me to elaborate more on this matter, please write in comments.

Comment: This is not fully true. For example, Israel's objection to the ICC specifically has to do with how it defines Genocide - occupying Palestinian territories by forcefully killing and / or chasing away Palestinians from their homes is considered (legally / technically) as a genocidal act . Israel objects to this part of the definition and believes this shouldn't be considered a genocidal act.

Comment: @sfxedit, Refrences please? Another question; When in history did an Israeli cabinet order its soldiers to kill or expell Arabs, in order to occupy their land? There are countless of places on the internet, where you can study this objectively.

Comment: [Israel must ratify the ICC statute](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/israel-must-ratify-the-icc-statute/). Israel has themselves warned some of its soldiers and officials that they could be susceptible to international prosecution [Why Israel fears the ICC war crimes investigation](https://www.theguardian.com/law/2021/mar/03/israeli-officials-start-to-feel-the-impact-of-icc-investigation).

Comment: Specifically, on Israel's major objection to the ICC: *Israel: Israel has reluctantly cast a negative vote. It fails to comprehend why it has been considered necessary to insert into the list of the most heinous and grievous war crimes the action of transferring population into occupied territory.* [UN diplomatic conference to concludes to establish ICC](https://press.un.org/en/1998/19980720.l2889.html).

Comment: @sfxedit, "transferring [its own] population INTO occupied territory" - not killing or expelling Palestinians. Israel is worried that some anti-Israel judges, who consider the disputed territories, "where Jews have lived for thousands of years uninterrupted - until the Jordanian invasion of 1948", as occupied territory, and would therefore rule that Jews who return to the historic Jewish quarter of Hebron (as an example) are committing a war crime.

Comment: As an indian, I am not anti-Israel or anti-jew. But I personally am very anti-Netanyahu because I consider him to to be a power hungry right-wing religious fundamentalist. In my opinion, Israel used to be a more compassionate state before him. It is an undeniable fact that Palestinians have been displaced to make room for Israeli jews in some areas. Whether the Palestinians were physically harmed during the process is debatable as Hamas also comes into the picture, and we know that Israel has faced terrorism from them. Note though that ICC wanted to investigate Hamas abuses too.

Comment: @sfxedit, Wow, too many misconceptions in one place. While every politician is power hungry, Netanyahu isn't religious at all. And religion should not be considered a problem by a true democratic person. Israel used to be a more leftist country before the failed attempt to build a succesful peace-loving partial Palestinian state in Gaza. The Hamas takeover of Gaza proved to the vast majority of Israelis that a peaceful Palestine in the near future is an illusion. Islamic terror against Jews in the land of Israel, is some 1,400 years older than Hamas.

Comment: @sfxedit, The 1948 war between Israel and its Arab neighbors, caused major demographic changes to the area; Almost a million Jews escaped: Eastern Jerusalem, Judea and Samaria, Lebanon, Syria, Jordan, Egypt, Iraq, Libya, Tunisia, Morocco - to Israel. While about 750,000 Arabs living in Israel escaped to Jordan, Lebanon and Syria. This was not the official goal of any party in the conflict. It's a natural outcome of an ethnic - religious driven war. Any lecture focusing on one part of this war-result, while ignoring the other part, is designed to misguide you.

Comment: Politicians like Netanyahu are themselves not fanatic, but use religion in their politics - Right-wing religious fundamentalism is based on *religious identity politics* that encourages hating one group while glorifying another. Jews have lived alongside muslims in the middle east peacefully for centuries. In fact, Jews historically were always more comfortable living among the muslims, than with Christians, because they were more accepted by the muslim community (as Islam considers the Jews as brethren - [people of the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_of_the_Book)). (1/2)

Comment: The conflict between Arabs and Israel has only widened because of the politics of right-wing religious fundamentalism on *both* sides. On the Israeli side, I identify this with Netanyahu. India is quite familiar with religious identity politics and violence but has learned to deal with it more peacefully than Israel because we had good political leaders who encouraged us to eschew hatred and build relationship with other religious community. (It is only now, that a right-wing religious fundamentalist called Narendra Modi grabbed power that religious hate has returned to India). (2/2)

Comment: @sfxedit, Oh, repeating lies don't make them true. It's only under Netanyahu that Palestinian terrorism against Jews is at a record low. Under leftist governments Israel suffered hundreds of casualties monthly - study the intifadahs. Regarding life for Jews in islamic countries throughout the last 1,400 years; It's difficult to go through every single detail of history, just as a head start, study the battle of Khyber, the pogroms of 1834 in Sefad and Hebron, the Farhud in Bagdad. And besides this, being better than the Crusades is no compliment.

Comment: *It's only under Netanyahu that Palestinian terrorism against Jews is at a record low.* - That has aged well.

Comment: @sfxedit, Of course, that's because he got too comfortable living next to the Gazan terrorists. If he would have knocked out their teeth at previous occasions, despite the backlash from "peace-minded-people", we wouldn't have been now after such a terrible terror attack.

Comment: Or, as I pointed out, these right-wing politicians never thrive in peace. By deliberately ignoring intelligence of a terrorist attack that other countries warned Israel about, Netanyahu now has an opportunity to distract the Israeli public from his failures with a war and trying to be a war hero, to ensure he can stay on in power somehow.

Comment: @sfxedit, "By deliberately ignoring intelligence of a terrorist attack" - that's an improvable blood libel.

Comment: Yes, and very convenient for them as the truth can only be proved by an investigation into the intelligence failure when the opposition is in power. By the time Netanyahu is thrown out of power, he and his coterie would have enough time to cover up their tracks.